# how to make responsive form on onepage

Tags: forms, image, responsive

I'm making a onepage website. 
and Red image with input boxes and Blue image with table putted on the second big image as you can see below,

[image: Red/Blue Images]

and my code is..

```html
<section id="section01" style="padding-top:70px;margin-top:70px;display: table;width:100%;height: 100%; text-align: center; background: url(img/main_02.jpg) bottom center no-repeat #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;">
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;">
            
            <table style="width: 100%;margin-top:100px;">
         <tr>
          <td style="width:50%;text-align: right;padding-right: 10px;">
           <img src="img/contact1.png" style="width:100%;max-width: 425px;" >     
     <input type="text" style="position: absolute;width:100%;max-width: 132px;color: #000; left: 420px;">
     <input type="text" style="position: absolute;width:100%;max-width: 132px;color: #000; left: 420px;">
          </td>
          <td style="width:50%;text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;">
           <img src="img/contact2.png" style="width:100%;max-width: 425px;" >           
     <table style="position: absolute;">
     <tr><td>1111</td></tr>
     </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        
        
        
    </section>
```

I was trying to put "position:absolute; left:xx px" tags , but if change resolution of screen, then result become mess.
I don't know when resizing screen, how to keep tag position?
need be responsive website... 
please advise me..

Comment: Use <div> element instead of table to stop breaking responsive design.

Comment: thanks!!!! I'm getting it!!